# Drupal 7 Multiple Select Joins Syntax

Tags: sql, database, drupal, join

Having real trouble getting my head around multiple joins. Can anyone tell me why this is wrong please?

****EDIT****

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('file_usage', 'fu', 'fu.id = n.nid');
$query->join('field_data_field_featured_image', 'ffimage', 'ffimage.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->join('file_managed', 'fm', 'fm.fid = n.nid');

$query
->fields('fu', array('id'))
->fields('fm', array('filename'))
->fields('ffimage', array('field_featured_image_title'))
->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
->condition('n.type', 'work')
->orderby('n.nid', 'DESC')
->range(0, 20);

$result = $query->execute();
foreach ($result as $record) {
echo '<li>';    
echo '<div class="home_text"><h1>'.$record->title.'</h1></div>';
echo '<a href="...some_node/';
echo $record->id;
echo '">';
echo '<img src="...some_files/';
echo $record->filename;
echo '" width="960px" height="615px" />';
echo '</a>';
echo '</li>';   
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Really sorry was a silly error not finding a field. This now works but it's not joining correctly ie. its outputting an incorrect list of images, the titles and urls appear to be correct but they're not lining up. Sigh.

Comment: The problem is with the last join `$query->join('file_managed', 'fm', 'fm.fid = n.nid');` I just need one field from it (the filename) but it seems to make sense to join it. How else can I just get the filename?

Comment: **Solved.**

Apparently the last join should have read:
`$query->join('file_managed', 'fm', 'fm.fid = fu.fid');`

I still don't understand why I can join 'file managed' id to 'file usage' id. When I can't to 'node' id. Thanks to KerrM anyhow.

Comment: **Last edit - to answer my own question**... there's no common column between fm and node. So you have to join fm to fu and then join fu to node who do share a common column. (I hope that's correct - sheesh).